# How to apply CSS transition effect/animation by jQuery forcefully

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has been used in a web application. There is toggle navigation for sidebar drawer/navigation which should be animated by default (as bootstrap toggle navigation is animated). But, unfortunately, there was no animation. So, I have applied this:

```
.navbar-collapse {
   width: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
.navbar-collapse.expanded-menu.in {
   width: 95%;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

It worked at the time of expanding the sidebar, but at the time of closing it didn't work. If I apply this jQuery, it won't help eighter.

```
$('body').on('click', '.navbar-toggle', function() {
       $('.expanded-menu.in').animate({"width":"95%"}, 500);
});
$('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
       $('.navbar-toggle').click();
       $('.expanded-menu').animate({"width":"0px"}, 500);
});
```

So, how to apply animation/sliding effect forcefully by jQuery/CSS at this type of situation.

[Fiddle Work](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/page88pm/3/)

N.B: If I remove `opacity` from my CSS, sliding effect work at the fiddle. But, at my web application, it don't work anyway at the time of closing sidebar. So, I need to know how to apply animation/sliding effect when default CSS/jQuery method don't help.

Answer (score 0):

Change css to:

```
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

and JS

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
   $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in');
});
```

I will say I'm not totally clear on why the css change works as I don't know the ins and outs of BS JS